# Conceptual question on helmholtz equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics

Given the homogeneous Helmholtz Equation $[\triangledown ^2 + \kappa^2] E= 0$, I understand $\kappa$ represents the wavenumber $\omega_0 / c$. In light of this, what physical meaning can be taken from this equation when $\kappa = 0$ and the equation becomes $\triangledown^2 E = 0$.

From my reading I understand the LaPlace equation representing the final form represents the harmonic solutions, but I am challenged conceptually at the difference in the two forms.

Comment: Can you be any clearer about what your question is. Laplace's equation applies in electrostatics, where $k=0. The Helmholtz equation is a generalisation to the time-dependent case.

Comment: Sure thing @RobJeffries. The Helmholtz equation, as I understand it, describes the solution at a specific frequency $\omega_0$ (remembering that I equate $\kappa = \omega_0 / c$. Under this condition, there appears to be a specific meaning to the solution.  However, when $\kappa=0$, the equation is still valid for a series of harmonic solutions. Given the homogeneous nature (that the Helmholtz and Laplace eqs given equal 0), I believe the system to be source free.

Given the above, when no frequency $\omega_0$ is being evaluated, how should I understand the physical meaning of $\kappa$?

Comment: $\kappa = 0$ doesn't mean that aren't evaluating a frequency, it means that we're evaluating $\omega_0 = 0$.  This is he steady state of the system in question.  In case there's any confusion, the harmonic nature of the solutions isn't really related to the fact that the Helmholtz equation is used for waves.

Comment: @user3823992, so I think you've helped me describe what my real conceptual issue is. What does the harmonic nature relate to?  I feel as if I'm missing something rather silly, but I'm just not connecting the dots here.

Comment: @Drew, for fixed $\kappa$ you're just looking for the function that satisfies the Helmholtz equation and the boundary conditions.  A series of functions is just one way of constructing that solution. In practice (complex geometry) you might construct approximations differently (numerically)

Comment: @user3823992, I get what you're saying. But understanding how to do the math (I am not having trouble solving the equations), and understanding what they means in a physical sense are two very different things.  I'm trying to find the latter.

Comment: For each k, you're looking at one of the modes or standing waves that can exist in the system. A "note" at which it can ring.

Comment: @user3823992, does that then imply that the $\kappa$ values represent higher harmonics to the fundamental frequency $\kappa = 0$?

Comment: @DrewW Pretty much yeah,  with the exception that I believe the fundamental would be the lowest non-zero $\kappa$.  The case of $\kappa = 0$ is the static case, there's no variation in time.  All of the others can be constant in the sense of having the same amplitude, but if you actually look at the measurable quantity (electric field, air pressure, etc.) it'll be oscillating at $omega$.  Picture a periodically forced mass hanging from a spring.  It will oscillate around the point where gravity balances the spring force ($0Hz$) but there will be oscillating motion on top of that.

Comment: @user3823992, that is very helpful, thank you.  You should sum up as an answer to the question and I can close the thread as answered.